# Django not passing context well

Tags: python, django

I was trying to pass a query set using context. But on template page the context is not working.
As I am implementing two queries in same view one query set is working fine but the other query is not passed well. Here is my view

```
# Create your views here.
def xray_result_view(request):
    q=query_holding_together.objects.filter(which_user=request.user)
    for x in q:  
        all_reports=xray_result.objects.get(which_query=x)
    print(all_reports.sys_gen_result)
    return render(request,'XRay/result.html',{'reports':all_reports})
```

when q is passed as template it is working as it should but it is not working for all reports. here is my template

```
{% extends "login/successful.html" %}
{% block middle_window %}
</div>
<div class="container adjust-ment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            Previous X-ray Results
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            Result
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        {% for y in reports.iterator %}
            File Name:<br>
            Date and Time of Upload:<br>
            System Generated Result:{{ y.sys_gen_result }}<br>
            Doctor's Comment on Result:{{ y.doctor_comment }}<br>
        {% endfor %}


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock middle_window %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a queryset in template, instead you are sending an object. Let me explain:

```
 for x in q:  
    all_reports=xray_result.objects.get(which_query=x)  #<-- Here
```

Here `all_reports` is a variable which has only a `xray_result` object. after the iteration is complete, `all_reports` will contain only the last object from `q`.

Instead, you can try like this:

```
def xray_result_view(request):
    all_reports=xray_result.objects.get(which_query__which_user=request.user)
    return render(request,'XRay/result.html',{'reports':all_reports})
```

And update the template:

```
{% for y in reports %}
    File Name:<br>
    Date and Time of Upload:<br>
    System Generated Result:{{ y.sys_gen_result }}<br>
    Doctor's Comment on Result:{{ y.doctor_comment }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, consider using `PascalCase` when writing Class names(as per pep8 standard).

Answer (score 0):

As @ruddra pointed out that there was problem with loop.
so for that I tried below workaround and it worked as a charm.

```
def xray_result_view(request):
    q=query_holding_together.objects.filter(which_user=request.user)
    all_reports=xray_result.objects.none()
    for x in q:  
        all_reports = all_reports | xray_result.objects.filter(which_query=x)
    for x in all_reports:
        print(x.sys_gen_result) 
    return render(request,'XRay/result.html',{'reports':all_reports})
```